# Get Action.Submit event from OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get the action event after a button is pressed on a thumbnail card generated in `OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync` method. All the samples around this have used only Action.OpenUrl. Anyone have tried this ?

```
protected override Task<MessagingExtensionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSelectItemAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, JObject query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var packages1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TicketClass>(query.ToString());
    var card = new ThumbnailCard
    {
        Title = $"{packages1.Title}, {packages1.ShortDescription}",
        Subtitle = packages1.LongDescription,
        Buttons = new List<CardAction>
            {
                new CardAction { Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Title = "Action 1 ", Value = "Show me more" },
                new CardAction { Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl, Title = "Action 2", Value = "" },
            },
    };
    var attachment = new MessagingExtensionAttachment
    {
        ContentType = ThumbnailCard.ContentType,
        Content = card,
    };

    return Task.FromResult(new MessagingExtensionResponse
    {
        ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
        {
            Type = "result",
            AttachmentLayout = "list",
            Attachments = new List<MessagingExtensionAttachment> { attachment }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You say you want to use Action.Submit which is an Adaptive Card action, but you're using a thumbnail card. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: @KyleDelaney My bad ! Have edited the question !

Comment: You haven't clarified anything though. Your title still says Action.Submit. Are you trying to use an Adaptive Card or a thumbnail card?

Comment: Are you still working on this?